# How can I select what user account will run a Windows service (run as) from command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, cron, windows-services

As one of the steps for installing [CRON](http://www.davidjnice.com/articles/cygwin_cron-service.html) daemon for [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) in Windows, it is worthful (not mandatory on WinXP, but seems to be greatly adviced since Win7) to change (along with some others modifications) the *run as* property of the just installed CRON service.
This is the GUI method window (sorry, my Windows is in spanish) where I can select any other user (in my example "cygrunsrv", but it could be any other):

[image: The "Run As" property - Executing a service as another account than "system"]

I have reviewed the docs, and the **sc** command does not seem to have that capability. All I found is this option to allow the service to interact with desktop:

```
sc config servicename type= interact type= own
```

but it is not the change I am searching for.
Is there a way to get this done via command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using `obj=` and `password=` params of `sc config`
*(Maybe it's edition dependent, but I was not able to find any information it is)*

Running `sc config /?` produces following options for me:

`CONFIG OPTIONS:
    NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
     type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec|adapt>
     start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
     error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
     binPath= <BinaryPathName>
     group= <LoadOrderGroup>
     tag= <yes|no>
     depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
     obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
     DisplayName= <display name>
     password= <password>`

Full description here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990290.aspx

Comment: The answer is correct. Example for the CRON Service: **sc config cron obj= ".\cygrunsrv" password= "MySecret"**. Quotes are adviced. Tested working from remote (SSH) console. Thanks, @wmz.

Comment: Best brief (but detailed) explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308298/how-to-set-windows-service-username-and-password-through-commandline