# Easiest way to grant "Log on as a service" to a Windows user from the command-line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to script an install where a service needs to be run as a user. I want to be able to specify the user.

Creating the user is easy through the [`NET USER /ADD`](http://www.windows-commandline.com/add-user-from-command-line/) command.

Specifying the user for the service can also be done: the [`SC CONFIG`](https://superuser.com/a/726374/14061) command [allows this](https://superuser.com/a/467735/14061).

Now the missing link: granting the user the ["Log on as a service"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957141.aspx) privilege as a [logon right](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976701.aspx) (`SeServiceLogonRight`). Is there a command for this? Or a simple script for PowerShell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to do this from a command line is definitely using [`NTRights.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657).

```
ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u jeroen -m \\%COMPUTERNAME%
```

Comment: An answer to this question - http://superuser.com/questions/309360/windows-7-equivalent-for-ntrights-exe - has a Powershell example.

Comment: @ultrasawblade thanks both of you; I'm going the `NtRights` route, but I'm glad there is a Plan-B when `NtRights` might become unavailable for one reason or another.

Comment: `ntrights +r SeServiceLogonRight -u %USERNAME% -m \\%COMPUTERNAME%` works, but `whoami /all` doesn't show any change. `secpol.msc` does show the change however, so I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Log out and log back in and whoami will list the new privilege

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen even after a reboot, `whomai /all` (with and without UAC token) list the right, but `secpol.msc` does.

Comment: Resource toolkit link is borked so this answer should either be updated with a good link or deleted (no shade to the answer, it's just outdated without a working link)

Answer (score 8):

I use [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org/) and [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).

```
cinst carbon -y
```

---

```
Grant-Privilege -Identity $username -Privilege SeServiceLogonRight
```

Based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155390/991267

Comment: Please elaborate why adding two dependencies would be better than one.

Comment: Chocolatey is a package manager, it simplifies install process. It's one of providers for OneGet. You can use PowerShell Gallery (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Carbon) instead.

Comment: Reminds me too much of http://xkcd.com/1654/ and http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/05/10/a-moment-of-nostalgia/

Comment: @Der_Meister - I can contest that this is a much more elegant solution. Cheers.

Comment: Although it should be SeServiceLogonRight instead of SeBatchLogonRight

Comment: If you don't mind installing Carbon it's way more elegant. You don't need choco, just use Install-Module Carbon