# Run CrashPlan service as administrator

Tags: windows-10, backup, administrator, crashplan

I am quite careful about what I do and don't open as attachments, but I am quite concerned about the ransomware wave that is roaming around lately.

I am backing up my computer (A windows 10 box) with CrashPlan everyday on and off site (one backup at the home, one in the office). But I am still concerned, because the drives are connected at my computer and if I am infected, a ransomware may start to crypt the backup files in the drive as soon as I connect the drive(s). And it might be too late before I realize that both my backups at work and home are encrypted.

I thought maybe I could change the ownership of the files to the Administrator user and revoke my user's rights to access them at all, but then CrashPlan will not be able to reach them as well.

So my question is: Is it possible to run CrashPlan service as administrator so that only CrashPlan service itself has access to them and my user won't be able to touch them?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new user with administrator access.
- [Grant that user the Logon as a Service right](https://superuser.com/questions/747094/easiest-way-to-grant-log-on-as-a-service-to-a-windows-user-from-the-command-li).
- Change the user account used to run the service to that new admin account.

[image: Service Properties Dialog]

- Restart the service.